# Why samsung S6 cannot expand status bar programmatically?

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I'm calling the method below to expand the status bar programmatically, it works well with most devices, however it does not work with Samsung S6 and other samsung devices. Why? And how can I expand the status bar programmatically in those devices?

```
public static void expandStatusBar() {
        try {
            Object statusBarService = MBApplication.getContext().getSystemService(NAME_STATUS_BAR_SERVICE);
            Class<?> statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
            Method expandMethod;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                expandMethod = statusBarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
            } else {
                expandMethod = statusBarManager.getMethod("expand");
            }
            expandMethod.invoke(statusBarService);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Samsung smartphones use some custom GUI widgets, so they are not supposed to work like on pure Android devices.

Comment: @Galya but Samsung S5 with 4.4 system works well

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it still doesn't mean that the new version is consistent with the old one. And Samsung's version of Android is private, so you will never know for sure what is exactly different. :) I've had many problems with their phones not using pure Android OS. The status bar is most definitely something that different manufacturers do differently.

Comment: @Galya thanks for your answer!